# Check for name_suffix

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to print the C.FIRST_NAME, C.MIDDLE_NAME, C.LAST_NAME & C.NAME_SUFFIX into one field. In some cases C.NAME_SUFFIX is null and if it is null then I don't want to concatenate it with other fields and if it is NOT then I want to concatenate it with the others including a space ' ' between them, same as I'm doing to C.MIDDLE_NAME in the below example.

```
CASE WHEN    C.MIDDLE_NAME = ' '
      THEN
         C.FIRST_NAME || C.MIDDLE_NAME || C.LAST_NAME
      ELSE
         C.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || C.MIDDLE_NAME || ' ' || C.LAST_NAME
   END
```

Thanks!

Comment: Delete this question.  Then ask another question and provide sample data and desired results.  Then, explain what you want to do and provide any code (such as the above) that attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: `''` is `NULL` in Oracle. So `c.middle_name = ''` will never be true (since `NULL` is never equal to any other value including another `NULL`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different solution, based on the `case` condition, Oracle's treatment of empty strings as null, and Oracle's and SQL standard's three-valued logic, looks like this:

```
with 
     c (       first_name, middle_name, last_name  , name_suffix) as (
        select 'John'    , 'D'        , 'Smith'    , ' '          from dual union all
        select 'Mary'    , 'Ann'      , 'Loury'    , null         from dual union all
        select 'Chris'   , null       , 'Robson'   , 'III'        from dual union all
        select 'Greg'    , 'Z.'       , 'Olson'    , 'Jr.'        from dual union all
        select 'Helen'   , ' '        , 'Webb-Hunt', ' '          from dual
     )
select first_name || ' ' ||
         case when middle_name != ' ' then (middle_name || ' ') end ||
         last_name ||
         case when name_suffix != ' ' then (' ' || name_suffix) end
       as full_name
from c;
```

Result:

```
FULL_NAME
-----------------------
John D Smith
Mary Ann Loury
Chris Robson III
Greg Z. Olson Jr.
Helen Webb-Hunt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure why you're not including the spaces in this concatenate:

C.FIRST_NAME || C.MIDDLE_NAME || C.LAST_NAME

But, regardless, you're probably better off rewriting this using NVL (I'm more familiar with MSSQL and I think you're using Oracle, but this should be the Oracle equivalent of MS's "ISNULL"). So, you can simply account for any NULLs by writing it this way:

C.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || NVL(C.MIDDLE_NAME,'') || ' ' || C.LAST_NAME || NVL(C.NAME_SUFFIX,'')

That way if they're null or blank you just normalize them to blank. If you have a lot of examples where there is a space, then you could probably just use TRIM to cut those down to a ''. For example

TRIM(LEADING ' ' FROM NVL(C.MIDDLE_NAME,''))

Then you don't need a case statement at all. Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: In Oracle an empty string is the same as `NULL` so `NVL( value, '' )` is the same as `NVL( value, NULL )` which is the same as just `value`.

Answer (score 0):

`RTRIM( value )` will remove all the trailing spaces from the `value` string; so, if you prepend a space to `value` and then use `RTRIM()` then if `value` is `NULL` or comprised entirely of spaces then the entire string will be stripped away leaving a `NULL` which will not change the concatenation:

```
C.FIRST_NAME
|| RTRIM( ' ' || C.MIDDLE_NAME )
|| ' ' || C.LAST_NAME
|| RTRIM( ' ' || C.NAME_SUFFIX )
```

**Oracle Setup**:

Thanks to @mathguy for the test data.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( first_name, middle_name, last_name, name_suffix) AS
SELECT 'John',  'D',   'Smith',     ' '   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mary',  'Ann', 'Loury',     null  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Chris', null,  'Robson',    'III' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Greg' , 'Z.',  'Olson',     'Jr.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Helen', ' ',   'Webb-Hunt', ' '   FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT C.FIRST_NAME
        || RTRIM( ' ' || C.MIDDLE_NAME )
        || ' ' || C.LAST_NAME
        || RTRIM( ' ' || C.NAME_SUFFIX )
       AS full_name
FROM   table_name c;
```

**Output**:

```
FULL_NAME             
-----------------------
John D Smith            
Mary Ann Loury          
Chris Robson III        
Greg Z. Olson Jr.       
Helen Webb-Hunt
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad I didn't post the complete question.

Actually I want to print the C.FIRST_NAME, C.MIDDLE_NAME, C.LAST_NAME & C.NAME_SUFFIX  into one field so, in some cases C.NAME_SUFFIX is null. If it is null then I don't want to add it with other and if it is NOT then I want to add it with the others including a space ' ' between them, same as I'm doing to C.MIDDLE_NAME.

Hope this time I'm clear.

Comment: @psftdeveloper - MT0's solution already does everything you need. I tested it on the sample inputs I just posted (with my solution which is different from MT0's) - his solution produces exactly the same results as mine. As MT0 explained, if `name_suffix` is null or empty or a space, then the RTRIM in the last line of his code will collapse everything in that last line to an empty string. Otherwise he is adding a space and the suffix.

Comment: @psftdeveloper The query I posted does exactly what you want - if `middle_name` or `name_suffix` are `NULL` or any number of space characters then they will be ignored; otherwise they will be added with a preceding space.